# How do extract query-like results from a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a relatively simple nested dictionary as below:

```
emp_details = {
    'Employee': {
        'jim': {'ID':'001', 'Sales':'75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}, 
        'eva': {'ID':'002', 'Sales': '50000', 'Title': 'Associate'}, 
        'tony': {'ID':'003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}
    }
}
```

I can get the sales info of `'eva'` easily by:

```
print(emp_details['Employee']['eva']['Sales'])
```

but I'm having difficulty writing a statement to extract information on all employees whose sales are over 50000.

Comment: What kind of difficulties? what have you tried? what did not work?

Comment: `emp_details['Employee']` is a dict. You can loop over the keys and values of a dictionary: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3294889/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use one statement because the list initializer expression can't have an `if` without an `else`.

Use a for loop:

```py
result = {} # dict expression
result_list = [] # list expression using (key, value)
for key, value in list(emp_details['Employee'].items())): # iterate from all items in dictionary
    if int(value['Sales']) > 50000: # your judgement
        result[key] = value # add to dict
        result_list.append((key, value)) # add to list
print(result)
print(result_list)
# should say:
'''
{'jim': {'ID':'001', 'Sales':'75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}, 'tony': {'ID':'003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}}
[('jim', {'ID':'001', 'Sales':'75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}), ('tony', {'ID':'003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'})]
'''
```

Comment: This worked beautifully...exactly what I needed for my little task on hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Sales` is of `String` type.

Therefore, we can do something like this to get the information of employees whose sales are over 50000 : -

**Method1 :**
If you just want to get the information : -

```py
emp_details={'Employee':{'jim':{'ID':'001', 'Sales':'75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}, \
                         'eva':{'ID':'002', 'Sales': '50000', 'Title': 'Associate'}, \
                         'tony':{'ID':'003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}
                         }}
                         
for emp in emp_details['Employee']:
    if int(emp_details['Employee'][emp]['Sales']) > 50000:
        print(emp_details['Employee'][emp])
```

It print outs to -:

```
{'ID': '001', 'Sales': '75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}
{'ID': '003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}
```

**Method2 :** You can use Dict and List comprehension to get complete information : -

```py
emp_details={'Employee':{'jim':{'ID':'001', 'Sales':'75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}, \
                         'eva':{'ID':'002', 'Sales': '50000', 'Title': 'Associate'}, \
                         'tony':{'ID':'003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}
                         }}
                         
emp_details_dictComp = {k:v for k,v in list(emp_details['Employee'].items()) if int(v['Sales']) > 50000}
print(emp_details_dictComp)

emp_details_listComp = [(k,v) for k,v in list(emp_details['Employee'].items()) if int(v['Sales']) > 50000]
print(emp_details_listComp)
```

Result : -

```
{'jim': {'ID': '001', 'Sales': '75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}, 'tony': {'ID': '003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'}}

[('jim', {'ID': '001', 'Sales': '75000', 'Title': 'Lead'}), ('tony', {'ID': '003', 'Sales': '150000', 'Title': 'Manager'})]
```

Comment: This worked beautifully albeit without the names, but that can be extracted.

Comment: @TonyR If you found my solution useful you can mark it as accepted.